# Gathering Dependencies w/ Netbeans and Maven

Tags: maven, netbeans, apache-poi

I have an existing Project I am working on. I got tired of downloading individual Jar files and importing them into my project's library. I decided to experiment with the Services->Maven.

I need to use Apache POI in my project. I can search and find the Apache POI Library, but how do i added it to my Project so that all dependencies are also present? I am currently getting errors like the following

> java.io.IOException: org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap
>       at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(WorkbookFactory.java:353)
>       at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.createXSSFWorkbook(WorkbookFactory.java:316)
>       at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:59)
>       at Tufin.InterfaceCommand.run(InterfaceMagicCLI.java:432)
>       at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:1666)
>       at picocli.CommandLine.access$900(CommandLine.java:144)
>       at picocli.CommandLine$RunAll.handle(CommandLine.java:2094)
>       at picocli.CommandLine$RunAll.handle(CommandLine.java:2053)
>       at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:1872)
>       at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:1801)
>       at Tufin.InterfaceMagicCLI.main(InterfaceMagicCLI.java:81)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap

Comment: Add the Apache POI dependency to your pom.xml.  Looks like version 4.1.1 is the latest from Oct 2019.  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi

Comment: This is my first time, how do i do that with the bundled maven in netbeans?

Comment: You have to create a pom.xml that spells out your dependencies.  Did you do that?  Maven only does what you ask it to do.  I don't use NetBeans; it's IntelliJ for me.  There's a Maven bundled into it, but it lies dormant until I write a pom.xml and call a lifecycle task.